# Visual studio code extension: How can I add error markers to files in the explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have written a validator for my vscode extension, which uses a `DiagnosticCollection` to set errors for files. This works and the errors are shown when a file is opened.

I would now like to mark files in the explorer, so that it is easy to find files with errors. Here is an example]of how it looks in Eclipse:

[image]

Is it possible to do this in a vscode extension? Is there already an extension doing this?

Comment: Hey did you find something?

Comment: No, but I am still hoping that it will be implemented soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/178) asking something related to Git, but not as open as you want. Maybe using the API described in [this another issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15485) you could create a new panel with the marked files.

It is still experimental, BTW...